# Not Able To Initiate a Class in Main Coding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i trying to call a form as show dialog in in main coding

i have added below screen shot to help you guys under what i am asking. I have tried search on the internet but wasn't able to find a solution too.

but itemsDeleteScreen,itemsEditScreen and AddScreens works perfectly

image screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66du.png

the items DeleteScreen Code : (Which Works)

```
itemsDeleteScreen deleteItem = new itemsDeleteScreen();
            deleteItem.ShowDialog(this); // loads the Delete Items Screen
```

the StockInsScreen Code : (Whic Does not Work)

```
stockInsScreen stkIns = new stockInsScreen();
            stockInsScreen.ShowDialog(this);
```

the error which i getting when i compile is

```
The type or namespace name 'stockInsScreen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Please paste your code instead of providing an image. The image background makes it hard to read!

Comment: i have added bigger picture and also coding thanks for the help :)

Comment: Have you tried to add the reference of your namespace containing the class stockInsScreen in your code. Use the `using` directive

Comment: using expoLightWarehouseSystem.Stock_Management.You did not include namespace.

Comment: @RT i have tired it but works that particular screen and not working for others

Comment: @restless it shows my expoLightsWareHouseSystem doesn't have property called Stock_Mangement

Comment: @AlstonAntony:Navigate to StockInScreen Class and check the namespace, it would be like(yourproject.foldername) and add that name space in the class you want to use.

Comment: @restless thanks mate that worked if you paste that in answer i will accept the answer and thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to StockInScreen Class and check the namespace, it would be like(yourproject.foldername) and add that name space in the class you want to use.(Source:From Image you have provided).For information about namespace,look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx